# scipy linprog suboptimal solutions

Tags: optimization, scipy

Trying to test a very simple optimization problem, but having trouble seeing what is going on with scipy.optimize.linprog

input_vector = -np.array([-1.,-1.,-1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,0,0,0])

A_upper = np.array([np.ones(len(input_vector)),-np.ones(len(input_vector))])

b_upper = np.array([.1,0.1])

opt_res = sp.optimize.linprog(c = input_vector, A_ub = A_upper, b_ub = b_upper )

Answer:

opt_res

status: 0

slack: array([ 0. ,  0.2])

success: True

```
 fun: -0.10000000000000001

   x: array([ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.1,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ])
```

message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 1

Surely [0.333,0.333,0.333,-0.25,-0.25,-0.25,-0.25] is a better solution that adheres to the constraints. And, yes, I know, this is the tip of the iceberg...the proposed solution could be multiplied with a positive scalar.

What am I missing here? Many thanks in advance.

Sam

Answer (score 1):

`linprog` is correct. As you did not provide any bounds, `linprog` will assume all variables are non-negative. See the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) (parameter `bounds`). If you want to allow negative values you need to specify this explicitly.

This default behavior is not unusual for LP solvers.